# Script from cron sends >50 mails on errors, 1 on success

Tags: python, email, cron, smtplib

I have an issue which I really cannot figure out.

The following snippets from my Python script zips a directory and sends a mail on success. It also sends a mail if an error occured. And here is the issue:

When I execute the script **manually**, everything works fine. 
**1 mail on success, 1 mail if an error occured.**

If the script is run from cron though, **I reveive over 50 emails if an error occures (on success only one)!** All mails have the same content (the error message), and all mails are sent at the same time (exact as "hh:mm").

This is the script snippet:

```py
def backup(pathMedia, pathZipMedia):
    [...]

    try:
        createArchive(pathMedia, pathZipMedia)
    except Exception as e:
        sendMail('Error in zipping the media dir: ' + str(e))
        sys.exit()

    sendMail('Backup successfully created!')


def sendMail(msg):
    sent = 0
    SMTPserver = '[...]'
    sender =     '[...]'
    destination = ['...']

    USERNAME = '[...]'
    PASSWORD = '[...]'

    text_subtype = 'plain'

    subject='Backup notification'
    content=msg

    try:
        msg = MIMEText(content, text_subtype)
        msg['Subject'] = subject
        msg['From'] = sender

        conn = SMTP(SMTPserver)
        conn.set_debuglevel(False)
        conn.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
        try:
            if (sent == 0):
                conn.sendmail(sender, destination, msg.as_string())
                sent = 1
        finally:
            conn.quit()

    except Exception as e:
        sys.exit()
```

My crontab is the following:

```
## run the backup script every 3 days at 4am
* 4 */3 * * /root/backup.py >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I fixed the orrucring errors now, but it still might happen again. 
And I'm really curious about why this issue occurs!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `*` at the beginning of your crontab line says "run this job every minute".

Presumably a successful run of the first job at 4:00 causes the following 59 runs to find that no work needs to be done, therefore they don't attempt to create a backup and they exit quietly without sending email.  But an unsuccessful run at 4:00 will leave work to be done by the next job at 4:01, and again the minute after that, and so on until 4:59.  All of those jobs try to create a backup and all of them fail, so you get something like 60 failure emails.  (Or fewer if one of the jobs manages to succeed, breaking the chain of failures.)

To fix the crontab line to run the job only one time at 4:00am, change the first `*` to a `0`.

I don't know why your failure emails all have the same timestamp.  Are you certain that they're all exactly the same?  If so, perhaps they're being batched by your mail system and are assigned a `Date` header at the time the batch is processed.  Or perhaps all of the jobs are started by `cron` and then they all wait, blocked until some system timeout or other event occurs, and then they all experience the failure simultaneously and all send emails at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Sounds like this could be the solution. 

Will try it and wait if some errors occur again!
Didn't know there is a difference between success and error for crontabs...

Comment: `cron` does behave differently if a `crontab` job fails, but what I'm suggesting here is that _your script_ behaves differently if it is run 10 times and the first run succeeds, versus if it is run 10 times and all of the runs fail.  If your script discovers that nothing needs to be backed up, because a previous run of the script succeeded a few seconds earlier, what does it do?  Does it just exit without sending email?  That would match the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: The script does not do any checks, when it's run, it zips the respective directory. 
However, I tested it to fail when run from cron and now, after changing the `*` to `0` as you suggested it also sends only one mail if it fails so that *was* the mistake :)